# Alternative for deprecated TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-tablayout

I was using a set of regular buttons to change the property a discrete seek bar modifies the value of. Touching one of the buttons would change the value a property, whose setter will then change the min/max of the seekbar. This property is also used in `onProgressChanged` of the seek bar to determine which property to change the value of.

I wanted some kind of indicator that would move with an animation between those buttons. I found `TabLayout` which provides this functionality.

The only issue is that it is a part of the deprecated Support Library. Its [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout) page points to AndroidX, in which I could not find a valid replacement.

Is there a good alternative to `TabLayout`, or should I just continue using it?

Comment: Use [`com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/)

Comment: @NileshRathod that is exactly what I need. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to use **`com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

For more information please check [**`Tab Layout`**](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/)