# Tablayout for Appbarlayout

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:tabMode="scrollable">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab1" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab2" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab3" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab4" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab5" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab6" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab7" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab8" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab9" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab10" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab11" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab12" />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".TabActivity" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I earlier asked on question on [TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915983/tabhost-is-deprecated) from that duplicate I notice in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10297560/15088920) that `TabHost` isn't deperecated. `TabLayout` is deprecated. Would it be better if I use `TabLayout`? If not than what I should use what is the alternative of `TabLayout`? Here is the [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout). In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095480/alternative-for-deprecated-tablayout) `AskNilesh` is saying to use `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`. But, we use it for `TabLayout`. I tried to create Tabbed Activity
[image]

It is also containing `TabLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to use `TabLayout` just because `TabHost` [is in fact deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost) (and `TabLayout` isn't). check out doc, not SO questions...

> This class was deprecated in API level 30.
> new applications should use fragment APIs instead of this class: Use TabLayout and ViewPager instead.

Comment: But, my question is how to get scrollable? In `TabWidget` I am unable to set `scrollable`/`tabMode`. I want `tab` like play store

Comment: well, no, you have two questions in your post: `Would it be better if I use TabLayout? If not than what I should use what is the alternative of TabLayout?` and not a single `scollable` word

Comment: So, what would you suggest for scrollable?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar so close to scollable feature of `TabHost`/`TabLayout`, sorry...